# FPDF Footer get variable declared on foreach line

Tags: php, variables, foreach, footer, fpdf

I declared a variable named "$shop" like this:

```
foreach($shop_list as $shop)
    function_that_writes_pdf_files($shop);
```

And I want to use $shop in my footer. Is it possible ? I could use a variable by using

```
global $variable
```

But it doesn't work with $shop
If you have an answer or seen the answer somewhere, please share it

Comment: You should avoid global variables. Also, if what you trying is to pass the `$shop` variable into the `function_that_writes_pdf_files($shop)` you should declare that variable inside your `function_that_writes_pdf_files`, for example, `function function_that_writes_pdf_files($shop){ 
// now you can use $shop variable here }`
Also, you should add some more code to get better help! :)

Comment: What should I do instead of a global variable ? Plus $shop is one of the elements contained in $shop_list. I just need to get $shop in my Footer and I can't pass parameters to Footer function since AddPage calls it automatically

Comment: Just use an object property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a small function when you extend the fPDF class with your own name. The function does nothing more than set a public variable that holds the value of `$shop` which you may then use in your footer function.

```
class my_pdf extends FPDF {
    public $shop;
    public function setshop($input) {$this->shop = $input;}
    function Footer() {
        $this->Cell(15,5,$this->shop,0,0,'L');  // Using the value of shop here
    }  // end of the Footer function
}

$ourpdf = new my_pdf('P','mm','Letter');
foreach($shop_list as $shop) {
    $ourpdf->setshop($shop); // This sets the value of $shop to the fPDF class you created so the footer function may use it
    function_that_writes_pdf_files($shop);
}
```